# An order of 52 is placed and only 50 is passed through the API into Laravel DB

Tags: laravel, api, bigcommerce

Scenario: Orders placed with over 50 unique products are not being passed through the API correctly and are being cut off at 50 (An order of 52 is placed and only 50 is passed through the API into our Laravel database).

Where we add to increase products in the order in laravel code wise.

How to call order data API in laravel code

I tried in client.php

> path:\vendor\bigcommerce\api\src\Bigcommerce\Api\client.php

```
return self::getCollection('/orders/' . $orderID . '/products/'. '?limit=200&page2', 'OrderProduct');
```

Expected result: Limitation isn’t in place for logged in users.

Any help, experience and knowledge sharing would be appreciated.

Comment: Main Api: `https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{store_hash}/v2/orders/{order_id}/products?limit={limit}&page={page_no}`
Limit you can put 100 and page_no as 1 and store_hash and order_id you already have. 
If getCollection is not working you can run above query via Guzzle that will work fine.  You can also use bigcommerce own api mock to test : https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/orders/orders-api/order-products/getallorderproducts

Comment: Yes, it is a good idea. I fixed the issue. Post your suggestion as answer, I will mark as answer

Comment: sure will put it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main Api:

`https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{store_hash}/v2/orders/{order_id}/products?limit={limit}&page={page_no}`

Limit you can put 100 and page_no as 1 and store_hash and order_id you already have.

- If getCollection is not working you can run above query via Guzzle that will work fine.
- You can also use bigcommerce own api mock to test : https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/orders/orders-api/order-products/getallorderproducts